# When to use "cross-functional" or "cross-functionally"?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to find an answer as to how to use the compound word "cross-functional" correctly to describe working with a team from different departments.

I collaborated with a **cross-functional** team of six interns in building project goals and ideas.

or do I use "cross-functionally" instead?

I collaborated **cross-functionally** with six interns in building project goals and ideas.

If both sentences are correct, is it more on preference and style? I have researched both usages, but I need more clarity since English is not my first language.

Comment: *I worked with a team made up of members from different departments.*. There, now you can avoid the horrid *cross-functional(ly)* altogether.

Comment: @High Performance Mark Yes; people only _think_ it's impressive to speak ultra-high-registerally.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I am indeed impressed by *ultra-high-registerally* :-)

Comment: Just a thought on resumes: write what exciting things you did and what results those activities produced. Then leave off all tired words borrowed from others who copied them, too: teamwork, colleagial, challenging, passion. If you get lucky and a human being reads your resume, reward them by being the not-cookie-cutter Joel.

Comment: If the team members are from different departments, then they are intra-department team members. *I collaborated with an intra-department team of six interns to ideate project goals and ideas.*

Comment: "I collaborated with a cross-functional team of six interns in building project goals and ideas." I have no idea what you actually did. Sounds like brainstorming with the other interns. What did you produce? What was the lasting effect?

Comment: Maybe I'm thick, but I've got no idea what _cross-functional_ means (the dictionaries I rely on do not deign to record it). As a hiring manager, I'd be inclined to ask what prompted you to cross functions (a rather adversarial-sounding activity).

Answer (score 1):

**Cross-functional** is an adjective. It's the way you are describing something e.g. "*I used to work with cross-functional teams.*"

**Cross-functionally** is an adverb i.e. it describes the verb e.g. "*I used to work cross-functionally.*"

Both are correct and can be used based on the context.

Comment: What does 'cross-functionally' mean? (Working, oneself, in different areas and/or liaising with others working in different areas?) Is it in major dictionaries?